# Download directory/files from FTP location using python script

Tags: python, ftplib

Download not working in python?

I've written a simple python program, to get files from FTP location but when I execute it, it gives an error [Errno 13] Permission denied message.

My code is as follows. Any idea why it's not working ?

```
import ftplib
from ftplib import FTP, error_perm

def getFTPDir(dirpath):

    f = ftplib.FTP(ip, username, password)

    try:
        f.cwd(dirpath)
        nameList = f.nlst()
        oldest = nameList[0]
        newest = nameList[-1]

        newest = oldest

        newDirPath = dirpath +'/'+ newest

        print f.cwd(newDirPath)
        subNameList = f.nlst()

        for i in range (len(subNameList)):
            f.cwd( newDirPath + '/' + str(subNameList[i]) )
            nameList1 = f.nlst()

            filename = nameList1[i]
            print "downloading..............", filename


            f.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, open(os.path.join(destination,localPath),"wb").write)
            print filename + " downloaded"

            try:
                fhandle = open(filename, 'wb')
                f.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)

            except Exception, e:
                print str(e)

            finally:
                fhandle.close()

    except error_perm:
        return

    except Exception, e:
        print str(e)

    finally: 
        f.close()
```

Comment: Please say on what line the error occurs...

Comment: f.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, open(os.path.join(destination,localPath),"wb").write)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of ftplib says (emphasize mine):

> FTP.retrbinary(command, callback[, maxblocksize[, rest]])
>
> Retrieve a file in binary transfer mode. command should be an appropriate RETR command: 'RETR filename'. **The callback function is called for each block** of data received, with a single string argument giving the data block.

So there are 2 possible error causes here:

- `destination` and `localPath` could point to a non existent folder or to a non writable folder or file (BTW, you would rewrite same file on each iteration...)
- if the file in not transfered in one single block, you try to open the destination file for each block without closing anything

Do not do that, but keep on doing what you wrote on next lines, or even better use a with:

```
   try:
        localname = os.path.join(destination,localPath)
        # a spy to control the names, comment it out when it works
        print filename, " -> ", localname 
        with open(localname, 'wb') as fhandle
            f.retrbinary('RETR ' + filename, fhandle.write)

   except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
```

That way, you can see where you try to write...